# Is there a way to do 'modulo' on float types

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, modulo, floating-point-conversion

Simply that, it's just that when I put:

```
float f;
if(f%1){
//do something
//
```

It returns an error, is there a way to do modulo on float types or i have to do a conversion?
I am using xCode IDE and the Objective-C language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [fmod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmod):

```
double f = 2.5;
double g = fmod (f, 2.0); // => g = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

% is for integers. Try using fmod().